# unicode to python object conversion

Tags: python

Given a unicode object:

```
u'[obj1,obj2,ob3]'
```

How do you convert it to a normal list of objects?

Comment: What sort of objects were you hoping to make the list contain?

Comment: i subclassed the django.forms.widget class .. and the value_from_datadict  method returns a list of objects as a unicode string ..   i want to be able to get the list of objects not the unicode string..

Comment: Suspect this question is based on a misconception, ie from outputting the results in the terminal...

Comment: -1: Fix the question: "django.forms.widget class .. and the value_from_datadict method returns a list of objects " That's the real question.  Please delete this mess and start again with the **real** question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import ast
s = u'[obj1,obj2,ob3]'
n = ast.literal_eval(s)
n
[obj1, obj2, ob3]
```

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean this? Converting a unicode string to a list of strings.
BTW, you need to know the encoding when dealing with unicode. Here I have used utf-8

```
>>> s = u'[obj1,obj2,ob3]'
>>> n = [e.encode('utf-8') for e in s.strip('[]').split(',')]
>>> n
['obj1', 'obj2', 'ob3']
```

Comment: when object.__repr__  has been called ...  is there a way to reverse it? how do you get the objects not the string representations?

Comment: @mossplix, Yes, use eval for that purpose. >>>obj=repr(True);obj2=eval(obj);print obj2

Comment: @mossplix:  No, there isn't.  `repr()` has no fixed format, and can basically return an arbitrary representation of the objects contents.

Comment: `repr()` isn't required to return a representation of the objects in valid python syntax, and for the majority of objects it actually doesn't.  Basically only primitive types and standard containers have a `repr()`, which is valid Python syntax, and for these types, one should better use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()` for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I agree to usage of `ast.literal_eval` instead of `eval` for security reasons. Thanks for adding this. Yes agree to your other comment too. But for most common purposes, repr returns a string which be eval'ed back and there are instances when it wont

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is a unicode string.
To encode it e.g. as UTF-8 use `yourutf8str = yourunicodestr.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: That will turn it into a bytestring, but not a list of objects.

Comment: He posted a string, not a list ;)

Answer (score 0):

**When unicode data doesn't show unicode u...**

On exporting data from an excel table using openpyxl, my unicode was invisible. Use `print repr(s)` to see it

```
>>>print(data)
>>>print(type(data))
["Independent", "Primary/Secondary Combined", "Coed", "Anglican", "Boarding"]
<type 'unicode>
>>>print repr(data)
u'["Independent", "Primary/Secondary Combined", "Coed", "Anglican", "Boarding"]'
```

The fix:

```
>>>import ast    
>>>data = ast.literal_eval(entry)
>>>print(data)
>>>print(type(data))
["Independent", "Primary/Secondary Combined", "Coed", "Anglican", "Boarding"]
<type 'list'>
```